# Getting nearest feature point from other features in point layer?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, import, python-addin

How i can do this **Get the nearest feature point from the other features point in a point layer Point feature class**

and make it in script tool

Comment: import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\aseel\\Desktop\\Project_pointDistanc\\PointDistance.gdb"

in_features = "base"
near_features = "dependent"
out_table = "Distancebetween"
search_radius = "22000 Feet"

arcpy.PointDistance_analysis(in_features, near_features, out_table, {search_radius})                                                                                                              i do this but there`s something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Point Distance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm) -

```
arcpy.PointDistance_analysis (in_features, near_features, out_table, {search_radius})
```